# problem counting the cards in a blackjack game

Tags: python

i made a blackjack game and i'm having problems counting my cards with the aces. Can someone help me clean my code

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.bust = False
        
        self.hand = []
        self.hand2 = []
        self.name = str(name)
        self.handlist = []
        
    def hit(self):
        for i in self.handlist:
            response = ''
            while response != 'h' or response != 's':
                print(self.name)
                print(i)
                print("Do you want to hit or stand? (h/s)")
                print(self.gettotal(i))
                response = str(input())
                if response == 'h':
                    phand = i
                    card = pickacard(deck)
                    phand.append(card)
                    i = phand
                    phand = []
                    grade = self.gettotal(i)
                    if grade > 21:
                        self.bust = True
                        print(i)
                        print(self.gettotal(i))
                        print("Player busts!")
                        break
                else:
                    break
        
    def gettotal(self, hand):
        total = 0
        if hand == []:
            total = 0
            return total
        for i in range(len(hand)):
            
            t = int(hand[i][0])
            if t == 11 or t == 12 or t == 13:
                total += 10
            elif t != 1:
                total += t
            elif t == 1 and total < 22:
                total += 11
        if total > 21:
            i = len(hand)-1
            while i >= 0:
                t = int(hand[i][0])
                if t == 1:
                    total -= 10
                    break
                i -= 1
        t = 0            
        return total
```

i have those exemple:

player1

[['1', 'D'], ['11', 'C'], ['11', 'D'], ['1', 'H']]

Do you want to hit or stand? (h/s)

total = 21

player1

[['1', 'D'], ['10', 'D'], ['11', 'H'], ['1', 'H']]

Do you want to hit or stand? (h/s)

total = 21

Comment: `elif t != 1` followed by `elif t == 1` can be improved

Comment: You can't decide whether an ace should be 1 or 11 until you have the entire total for the hand.  You'll need to have a flag that says whether there is an ace in the hand.  After you have the entire total, if the total is less than 11, then make it an 11 by adding 10 to the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    def gettotal(self, hand):
        total = 0
        aces = False
        for card in hand:
            t = int(card[0])
            if t > 11:
                total += 10
            elif t == 1:
                aces = True
                total += 1
            else:
                total += t
        if aces and total <= 11:
            total += 10
        return total
```

And, by the way, any card game that shows 1, 11, 12 and 13 instead of A, J, Q, K is not worth playing.  Since you're storing the cards as strings anyway, why not just store the familiar letters?  It would take very minor changes to your code, and the user experience would be much better:

```
    def gettotal(self, hand):
        total = 0
        aces = False
        for card in hand:
            t = card[0]
            if t in "JQK":
                total += 10
            elif t == 'A':
                aces = True
                total += 1
            else:
                total += int(t)
        if aces and total <= 11:
            total += 10
        return total
```